# mysql query inconsistency

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query is giving me differing results on different rows and it should be giving me the same result on all rows.

Here is the query:

```
select * from 
    (SELECT mjla_db.StudentRecordTable2.studentId, 
            mjla_db.StudentTable2.lastName as `Last Name`, 
            mjla_db.StudentTable2.firstName as `First Name`, 
            sum(if(quizId=60,quizGrade,0)) as `Quiz 60`, 
            sum(if(quizId=64,quizGrade,0)) as `Quiz 64`, 
            sum(if(quizId=71,quizGrade,0)) as `Quiz 71`,
            (sum(quizGrade*(1-abs(sign(quizId-60)))) + 
                sum(quizGrade*(1-abs(sign(quizId-64)))) + 
                sum(quizGrade*(1-abs(sign(quizId-71)))) )/3 
                as Averages 
    FROM mjla_db.StudentRecordTable2, mjla_db.StudentTable2 
    where (mjla_db.StudentRecordTable2.studentId=mjla_db.StudentTable2.studentId) 
    GROUP BY studentId) as A 
where A.studentId 
in (select mjla_db.ClassStudentTable2.studentId 
    from mjla_db.ClassStudentTable2 
    where mjla_db.ClassStudentTable2.classId='CS3071F2011');
```

The number of quizzes are dynamic, number of students are dynamic.

---

Here is the contents of the table where `mjla_db.StudentRecordTable2.classId='CS3071F2011'`.

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| classId     | studentId | quizGrade | quizId |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| CS3071F2011 | A1        |      NULL |     60 |
| CS3071F2011 | A2        |      NULL |     60 |
| CS3071F2011 | A5        |      NULL |     60 |
| CS3071F2011 | A1        |      NULL |     64 |
| CS3071F2011 | A2        |      NULL |     64 |
| CS3071F2011 | A5        |      NULL |     64 |
| CS3071F2011 | A7        |      NULL |     64 |
| CS3071F2011 | A3        |      NULL |     64 |
| CS3071F2011 | A4        |      NULL |     64 |
| CS3071F2011 | A3        |      NULL |     60 |
| CS3071F2011 | A4        |      NULL |     60 |
| CS3071F2011 | A7        |      NULL |     60 |
| CS3071F2011 | A1        |      NULL |     71 |
| CS3071F2011 | A2        |      NULL |     71 |
| CS3071F2011 | A5        |      NULL |     71 |
| CS3071F2011 | A7        |      NULL |     71 |
| CS3071F2011 | A3        |      NULL |     71 |
| CS3071F2011 | A4        |      NULL |     71 |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+--------+
```

---

Here is the result of the query.

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
| studentId | Last Name | First Name | Quiz 60 | Quiz 64 | Quiz 71 | Averages |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
| A1        | harry     | thomas     |       0 |       0 |       0 |   0.0000 |
| A2        | harry     | willy      |       0 |       0 |       0 |   0.0000 |
| A3        | billy     | gregory    |       0 |       0 |       0 |   0.0000 |
| A4        | goat      | bobb       |       0 |       0 |       0 |   0.0000 |
| A5        | nogood    | tom        |       0 |       0 |       0 |     NULL |
| A7        | foobar    | dick       |       0 |       0 |       0 |     NULL |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
```

---

The expected result of the query would be for all the averages to be 0.0000, why are the last two varying?

Also, whenever i do the query so that i only get one student at a time A5 and A7 still show up as NULL and the rest show up fine...

---

A solution to this problem or an alternate query to achieve the same goal would be acceptable. My goal is to get a table that each row is a representation of each student in the class and their grades on all the quizzes and an average of all the quizzes that student.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your quizGrade values are NULL, which you're using in math calculations (`(sum(quizGrade*(1-abs(sign(quizId-60))))`. As soon as a db NULL enters into pretty much any kind of operation, the whole operation becomes null. The question shouldn't be why the last two are null, but why the first four AREN'T.

Comment: Any ideas why this is not working as intended? Or know of a better query for this operation?

Comment: doing multi-column transformations via SQL is highly painful, and extremely ugly, especially if/when you decide to add in yet another quiz. That sort of transformation should be client-side, after you've retrieved "simple" per-student data from a basic query.

Comment: I agree, but at this point the problem is basically unavoidable. Is there a different way to query to get the same intended results? Right now, it is only possible to change the query. And i am very curious as to why this is not working...

Answer (score 0):

Are students going to have more than one quizscore for the same quizid (in the example it is one-to-one as I imagine it should be)? If not then you could use

```
 avg( if(quizGrade, quizGrade, 0) ) as Averages
```

Answer (score 0):

For A7 there is no grade. This returns NULL in the average thing. The average of anything that has NULL in it will always be NULL.

The easiest way to fix this is to use the function `IFNULL`. This can replace a NULL value with something else. As in:

```
(sum(ifnull(quizGrade*(1-abs(sign(quizId-60))),0)) + 
sum(ifnull(quizGrade*(1-abs(sign(quizId-64))),0)) + 
sum(ifnull(quizGrade*(1-abs(sign(quizId-71)))),0 )/3 
as Averages
```

I hope I have placed the `(` correctly.